# evaluate expression in scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to create a directive for my date pickers here is the relevant code.

usage

```
<date-input open="openCalendar = true">
    <input ng-model="ctrl.model.theDate"
           uib-datepicker-popup="dd-MMMM-yyyy" 
           is-open="openCalendar">
</date-input>
```

directive

```
angular
    .module('common.directives')
    .directive('dateInput', function() {

        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            transclude: true,
            scope: {open:'&'},
            template: 'date-input-template',
        };
    });
```

template

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="date-input-template>
    <div class="input-group">
        <ng-transclude></ng-transclude>
        <div class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" ng-click="open()">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</script>
```

This works once. If I try to open the calendar a 2nd time, the date picker does not display. I'm sure I'm doing something wrong, just not sure what it is.

Any suggestions or guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your expression for `ng-click` needs to invoke `open`:

```
ng-click="open()"
```

**Edit:** You may want to use an object like `data.openCalendar = true` to avoid prototypal scope inheritance issues, or move the `openCalendar = true` expression into a function and invoke that function.

Comment: thank you. I changed `open` to `open()` but that only opens the calendar on the first click. If I close the calendar, and click the button a second time the calendar does not display. It seems like a problem with scope. But I don't know how best to debug that.

Comment: @JasonMeckley You may want to use an object for `openCalendar` like `data.openCalendar = true` to avoid prototypal scope inheritance issues, or move the `openCalendar = true` expression into a function and invoke that function.

Answer (score 0):

You should call the function with the expression

```
ng-click="open()">
```

Comment: thank you @sajeetharan. I updated my question, based on your response. The calendar still only opens once. I think it's a problem with scope variables, but I'm not sure how to debug that, or how to share variables across scopes